# why method onPostExecute on asynctask is never called

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I tried to **dismiss();** progressbar dialog when the load by using a method **onPostExecute** in webview when finished process.
my problem is when i run onPostExecute method in AsynTask is never executed ?

Note : i've read

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;
    EditText edInput;
    Button btnCari;
    String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        edInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        btnCari = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnCari.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                asynCaller myTask = new asynCaller();
                myTask.execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadWeb(String url){
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://"+url);
    }


    public class asynCaller extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            url = edInput.getText().toString();
            progressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Pesan","Memuat . . .",true);
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            publishProgress();
            return url;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            loadWeb(url);
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: What was the value of the return value of myTask.doInBackground(String... params)?  if null is returned or if you don't implement the @Override function correctly, then onPostExecute(String result) won't be called I believe.

Comment: ????? Why do you use an async task to let a webview load an url in on progress update? Makes no sense i would think.

Comment: greenapps is right. This isn't how you should be implementing a `ProgressDialog` for a `WebView`. Anyway, your problem is that the `ProgressDialog` that's showing isn't the one you're dismissing. The `show(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, boolean)` method that you're using is a static method of `ProgressDialog` that returns the instance that shows, but you're not keeping a reference to that one, and instead are dismissing the one that you initialize at the top of your `AsyncTask`, but that one is never shown.

Comment: Because method doInBackground can't handle UI for load web view

Comment: What's solution to loadwebview using asyntask ?